# Reputation does not change with Upvoting

Tags: discussion, reputation, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

this is my link to reputation:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/690854/thecodeparadox?tab=reputation

and you will notice at beginning of today's reputation some up vote don't reflect in reputation. I am getting worried, don't recognize the problem?

Please help.

Thanks..

Comment: You've hit the repcap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're near the 200 rep cap.  You can't earn more rep with just upvotes after you hit 200 (bounties and accepted answers don't count towards the cap).

Comment: will those up votes cancel?

Comment: @abdullah.abcoder:  They won't be counted.  Check Mat's comment in your original question for clarification.